# Realm Mobile platforms compatibility between versions

Tags: realm

I created a realm on react-native in this version: "realm": "^2.0.11".

But cannot be opened on a Obj-c project with 3.0.2 version! (latest)

What is the compatibility table between platforms?

Comment: What error did you get? Were you using the sync product?

Comment: No, actually, it's a shared container between Swift and React Native.